# How do I fix this buffer issue?

Tags: java, image, buffer, jmf

[image]

Basically I don't know what to do...

I downloaded the JMF library and inserted the library into the project. It was working fine until I came across this problem. Let me know what you think. Thanks!!!

Zev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could explicitly make `_buf` into a `javax.media.Buffer` by writing out its full name, like

`javax.media.Buffer _buf = frameGrabber.grabFrame();`

Alternatively, you could import all of the classes of `javax.media` by placing in your import statements (or above the class definition `public class mediaFunction`) :

`import javax.media.*;`

Or you could import specifically `javax.media.Buffer` so Java knows that Buffer really means javax.media.Buffer, by importing:

`import javax.media.Buffer;`

This [article on packages and imports](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) may help.

What I'm guessing is you imported java.nio.* or java.nio.Buffer, so it thinks that `Buffer` implicitly means `java.nio.Buffer`, not the buffer type that `frameGrabber.grabFrame()` returns, or in other words, `javax.media.Buffer`. Regardless, my first solution ought to fix your problem.

Comment: I have tried that, I should have included that I tried that. It's like I don't even have that API. Where would I find javax.media.Buffer?

Comment: Here is the documentation for [javax.media.Buffer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Buffer.html). Did you try compiling with my suggestion(s)? I'm surprised that it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, they have been tried and I have looked at the documentation. I wondered if I had to "customize" JMF... I could not get it to run... still not sure what the problem is... like I said before... its like I don't have the API/ Library

Comment: I doubt you'd have to 'customize' JMF. The fact that it recognizes frameGrabber.grabFrame() returns a javax.media.Buffer seems to indicate you have the library. I'm absolutely puzzled :-p

Comment: That is a puzzle.  I definitely looks like Eclipse thinks the type `Buffer` belongs to the package `java.nio.Buffer`.  The red squiggles in the line below are another indication that the buffer you have is not the buffer it is expecting.  Are you sure there are no references to `java.nio.*` in that class?  Also, you might want to try cleaning the project (Project -> Clean...) and rebuilding it.  Check the Problems view too (Window -> Show View -> Problems) - you may have other classpath issues.

Comment: Another thing to try:  remove the explicit type declaration so you have just the following on one line:

    `frameGrabber.grabFrame();`

Now, put your cursor on that line and bring up Quick Fix (Ctrl+1 or Edit -> Quick Fix).  One of the options should be 'Assign to local variable'.  Hit that and see what it does.

Comment: @user516664  What error does it print out when you try my first suggestion (and if that doesn't work, try britishmutt's suggestions)

Comment: I do have java.nio.Buffer... and yet it wants something else, but I thought the error was saying I needed javax.media.Buffer... I tried cleaning it, but it still did not work. Also I am in netbeans... so I could not check out the Window > show view > problems... I don't believe I have quickfix due to me using netbeans... I not written enough code to test it for e.printstacktrace(); errors...

Comment: @user516664 are you SURE you changed the line `Buffer _buf = frameGrabber.grabFrame();` to `javax.media.Buffer _buf = frameGrabber.grabFrame();` and then compiled? It wants _buf to be a javax.media.Buffer

Comment: i restarted netbeans IDE and it worked  WOOT!  idk what happened, but it worked... wew.. that was frustrating... i did change it to javax.media.Buffer earlier... and its still that... so that and restart made it work   thanks everyone!!!